# Using CASE in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, case

Imagine the number of times people access google website across the globe(ID, Name, location, google (varchar) )
I want to query so that the result is displayed as follows

```
   Name : No.of times : Location : Google Website

   Joe  :   2         :  Singapore : google.com.sg
   Kim  :   3         :  Japan     : google.com.jp
```

Just my two cents.....Will the query below right?

```
 SELECT Name, Count(Name), Location, CASE WHEN Location = 'Singapore' THEN CONCAT('google','.com.sg')
                                     WHEN Location = 'Japan' THEN CONCAT('google','.com.jp')
                                     ELSE google END AS Website
 FROM db1
 GROUP BY Name, Location, Website
```

Because when I add CASE in the select statement, it keeps saying not a GROUP BY expression so I would like to check if my understanding is right...

Answer (score 1):

You have to either repeat the entire `CASE` expression in the `GROUP BY` clause, or use a subquery.  For the latter (less verbose) option:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        Name,
        Location,
        CASE Location WHEN 'Singapore' THEN CONCAT('google','.com.sg')
                      WHEN 'Japan' THEN CONCAT('google','.com.jp')
                      ELSE google END AS Website
    FROM db1
)

SELECT Name, Location, Website, COUNT(Name) AS cnt
FROM cte
GROUP BY Name, Location, Website;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the case statement in group by

```
 SELECT Name, Count(Name), Location, CASE WHEN Location = 'Singapore' THEN CONCAT('google','.com.sg')
                                     WHEN Location = 'Japan' THEN CONCAT('google','.com.jp')
                                     ELSE 'google' END AS Website
 FROM db1
 GROUP BY Name, Location, CASE WHEN Location = 'Singapore' THEN CONCAT('google','.com.sg')
                                     WHEN Location = 'Japan' THEN CONCAT('google','.com.jp')
                                     ELSE 'google' END
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually your understanding is right, Just one small change is needed.

You don't need to add `WEBSITE` into the `group by` expression as it is derived column based on the `Location` column which is already present in the `GROUP BY` clause.

So just remove `WEBSITE` from your `GROUP BY` clause and you are good to go:

> ```
> SELECT
>     NAME,
>     COUNT(NAME),
>     LOCATION,
>     CASE
>         WHEN LOCATION = 'Singapore' THEN CONCAT('google', '.com.sg')
>         WHEN LOCATION = 'Japan'     THEN CONCAT('google', '.com.jp')
>         ELSE 'google' -- if this is string then it must be wrapped in the single quotes
>     END AS WEBSITE
> FROM
>     DB1
> GROUP BY
>     NAME,
>     LOCATION; --,WEBSITE -- removed WEBSITE rfom GROUP BY clause
> ```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Do it in two steps:

1. Do the aggregation (`count()`) in a *derived table* (i.e. the sub-query, here named dt.)
2. Apply the `case` *expression* on its result:

```
    SELECT Name, Location,
           CASE Location WHEN 'Singapore' THEN CONCAT('google','.com.sg')
                         WHEN 'Japan' THEN CONCAT('google','.com.jp')
                         ELSE 'google'
           END AS Website,
           cnt
    FROM
    (
        SELECT Name,
               Location,
               count(Name) as cnt
        FROM db1
        GROUP BY Name, Location
    ) dt
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is fine -- if you want a separate row for each location.

If you just want at most three locations -- Singapore, Japan, and everywhere else -- then remove `location` from the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` and add the `CASE` to the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT Name, Count(Name), 
       (CASE WHEN Location = 'Singapore' THEN CONCAT('google','.com.sg')
            WHEN Location = 'Japan' THEN CONCAT('google','.com.jp')
            ELSE 'google'
        END) AS Website
FROM db1
GROUP BY Name, 
         (CASE WHEN Location = 'Singapore' THEN CONCAT('google','.com.sg')
               WHEN Location = 'Japan' THEN CONCAT('google','.com.jp')
               ELSE 'google'
          END);
```